# Install iOS App onto Multiple Devices with Free Developer Account

Tags: ios, xcode, demo

Fledgling iOS hobbyist here. I have a demo app I plan on presenting to a group of people in about a month. It is a simple app, and I am still on the free tier of the Apple Developer Program for now. For this presentation, I'm being provided loaner iPhones, iPads, and MacBooks to demo my app and its code on.

I do know that I am able to load my app onto at least two devices, but they are my own personal iPhone and iPad.

My question is this: With a free developer account, will I be able to 1) load my app onto multiple iPhones and iPads (that I do not own) to demo for the duration of this presentation; and 2) load the code into Xcode on multiple Macs (that I do not own) so that I can show the code to those present. Or will I have to take the plunge and purchase the full $99/year developer account.

This isn't a code question, I know - but the Apple Developer forums are not nearly as active, and I would like a clear answer on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Connect each iOS device to your dev machine and build your app on it. The device will ask you to trust the developer, which you can do in Settings. It's no different than debugging on your own device.
2. Are you showing the code or the finished app? If showing the code, make sure the other machine has Xcode, then transfer the code from your dev machine (by USB, network folder, GitHub, etc) and build on the new machine. If you are showing the finished app, make sure [Gatekeeper](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491) is set to at least "Mac App Store and Identified Developer"

Comment: 1. To clarify - there is no limit on the number of devices I can build my app onto? and 2. I'm showing the code on the MacBooks, and the finished app on the iPhones and iPads

Comment: There's no limit to how many devices you can run it on. But it's always best to test this out ahead of time. Something will always be not working come the big day.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the tips. And yes, that's part of the reason I asked this question! Want to be fully prepared when everything inevitably breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The quick workaround is you change the identifiers and install it on various phones. com.company.app1 and com.componay.app2 and install the same app on different device. Although with this push notifications and all services connected to identifier does not works.

Comment: Could you please detail which notifications and services you meant?

Comment: APN Notifications & services like App Payment, Game Center, etc